# react native custom style text input

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make custom style in react native text input. it's 6 textInput with little margin between them, like in the picture

[image]

that's my code, (temText is amount of textInput I want to create)

```
  const { container, pinInputStyle,pinInputStyle2 } = styles;
    const {styleUnder} = this.state;
    var indet = this.temText.map((i) => {
        return (
            <TextInput
                ref={ref => this.temText[i] = { myRef: ref, next: i + 1 }}
                type={'TextInput'}
                underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                autoCapitalize={'none'}
                autoCorrect={false}
                onChangeText={(value) => this._onChangeText(value)}
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'number-pad' : 'numeric'}
                autoFocus={i === 0}
                maxLength={1}
                key={i}
                onFocus={()=>this._onFocus()}
                onBlur = {()=>this._onBlur()}
                placeholderTextColor ="#3e445f"
                //onEndEditing = { this.verifyCode.bind(this) }
                enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={false}
                style={[pinInputStyle]}
            />
        )
    });
```

the styles

```
    export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flexDirection:'column',
        flex:1,

    },
    textViewStyle:{
        flexDirection:'row',
    },
   pinInputStyle:{
       marginLeft:calcSize(10),
       fontSize:calcSize(50),
       width:calcSize(20),
       alignSelf: 'center'
   },
   pinInputStyle2:{
       fontSize:calcSize(150),
   },
   codeStyle:{
       flex:1,
       flexDirection:'row'
   }
})
```

for now it's looks like this
but I need it more bigger the line\placeholder and the fontsize
[image]